# Admob Integration

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks, admob

I'm trying to add admob to my app and I'm confused with step 4 which is

> Under Other Linker Flags, add -all_load to both Debug and Release.

Is that under OTHER_LDFLAGS? How would I exactly do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
1. Go to target seetings of your project.

2. Now go to Build settings. In Search bar type " Other Linker Flags ". As shown below in image will appear on screen.
```

[image]

Now add -all_load to both Debug and Release.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason my linking setting doesn't have Other Linker flags... http://i.imgur.com/fLrH2.png

Answer (score 0):

Check this image to set Other Linker flag. hope helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason my linking setting doesn't have Other Linker flags... http://i.imgur.com/fLrH2.png